# Pygame Rect moves for one frame in the wrong direction after changing it -Snake

Tags: python, pygame

i just started a simple snake project an hour and a half ago but i got a little problem....
If i move the rect  first upwards and then into the right direction it goes right but for one frame downwards ... Obviously i know why but i dont know how to fix it... The problem is that the snake have to move and it have to either move down, right, left or upwards other directions arent allowed.

```
import pygame

import sys

pygame.init( )
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")


class Snake( ):

    def __init__(self):
        self.go = True
        pygame.init( )

        self.width_body = 20
        self.hight_body = 20
        self.current_position_x = 950
        self.current_position_y = 540
        self.current_direction_y = 0
        self.current_direction_x = 0
        self.player_speed_y = 0
        self.player_speed_x = 0
        self.FPS = pygame.time.Clock( )

        self.while_loop( )

    def while_loop(self):

        while self.go:
            screen.fill((50, 50, 50))

            for self.event in pygame.event.get( ):
                if self.event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit( )

                if self.event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if self.event.key == pygame.K_w and self.player_speed_y == 0:
                        if self.player_speed_x == 3:
                            self.player_speed_x -= 3
                        if self.player_speed_x == -3:
                            self.player_speed_x += 3
                        self.player_speed_y -= 3
                    if self.event.key == pygame.K_s and self.player_speed_y == 0:
                        if self.player_speed_x == 3:
                            self.player_speed_x -= 3
                        if self.player_speed_x == -3:
                            self.player_speed_x += 3
                        self.player_speed_y += 3
                    if self.event.key == pygame.K_a and self.player_speed_x == 0:
                        if self.player_speed_y == 3:
                            self.player_speed_y -= 3
                        if self.player_speed_y == -3:
                            self.player_speed_y += 3
                        self.player_speed_x -= 3
                    if self.event.key == pygame.K_d and self.player_speed_x == 0:
                        if self.player_speed_y == 3:
                            self.player_speed_y -= 3
                        if self.player_speed_y == -3:
                            self.player_speed_y += 3
                        self.player_speed_x += 3

            self.current_position_y += self.player_speed_y
            self.current_position_x += self.player_speed_x
            self.snake( )

            pygame.display.flip( )
            self.FPS.tick(60)

    def snake(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ('Red'),(self.current_position_x, self.current_position_y, self.width_body, self.hight_body))


Snake( )
```

Comment: *"it goes right but for one frame downwards ..."* - No. I cannot reproduce the problem. `print(self.current_position_x, self.current_position_y)` and you see that the movement is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to simplify the movement:

```py
def while_loop(self):

    while self.go:
        for self.event in pygame.event.get( ):
            if self.event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.go = False

            if self.event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if self.event.key == pygame.K_w and self.player_speed_y == 0:
                    self.player_speed_x = 0
                    self.player_speed_y = -3
                if self.event.key == pygame.K_s and self.player_speed_y == 0:
                    self.player_speed_x = 0
                    self.player_speed_y = 3
                if self.event.key == pygame.K_a and self.player_speed_x == 0:
                    self.player_speed_x = -3
                    self.player_speed_y = 0
                if self.event.key == pygame.K_d and self.player_speed_x == 0:
                    self.player_speed_x = 3
                    self.player_speed_y = 0

        self.current_position_y += self.player_speed_y
        self.current_position_x += self.player_speed_x

        screen.fill((50, 50, 50))
        print(self.current_position_x, self.current_position_y)
        self.snake( )
        pygame.display.flip( )
        self.FPS.tick(60)
        
    pygame.quit()
```